# Does a gigabyte GA-P55-USB3 need any BIOS settings changed with intel Lynnfield 2.93?

Tags: motherboard, bios

I bought and assembled a

```
GIGABYTE GA-P55-USB3 LGA 1156 Intel P55 USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
```

with a Intel Core i7-875K Lynnfield 2.93GHz LGA 1156 95W Quad-Core Unlocked Desktop Processor BX80605I7875K

It seems a little sluggish though. Sometimes it takes forever to start up/shut down. (though runs decent once it gets going) Do I need to change any of the BIOS settings to make it work optimally?

newegg links to hardware: 
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128425
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116368

For reference, this is my memory:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820145284

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so yet, update the bios to version F8. Do it in Safe Mode.

http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3440#bios

.